# Jquery click function not working when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm facing problem to trigger jquery click function. I want to hide phone number and email using jquery. The phone number and email only can see if using click the `<p>` tag.

Below is my jquery function that I already write;

```
function() {
    var $phone = '123456123',
        $email = 'info@youremail.com',
        phone = $('#phone'),
        email = $('#email');

    $(phone).click(function() {
        var text = $(this).text() == $phone ?
            'Click to view number' : $phone;
        $(this).text(text).toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(email).click(function() {
        var text = $(this).text() == $email ? 
            'Click to view email' : $email;
        $(this).text(text).toggleClass("active");
    });

}();
```

When I run the code, I click on the number tag but nothing change.

Comment: What is not working about your code? Are you getting a specific error message? Does it load up and then not do anything? Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where's your css code for the `active` class? And do you have css for when it is inactive?

Comment: Use `$('#phone').click()` or `phone.click()` -- you don't need the extra "$" the way you have it.

Comment: You should check the browser’s console for errors and include them in your question if you can’t solve the problem based on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed a small fix on js. 
See it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/4d6y78Lr/)

```
$(function() {
    var $phone = '123456123',
          $email = 'info@youremail.com',
            phone = $('#phone'),
              email = $('#email');

    $(phone).click(function() {
        var text = $(this).text() == $phone ?
            'Click to view number' : $phone;
        $(this).text(text).toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(email).click(function() {
        var text = $(this).text() == $email ? 
            'Click to view email' : $email;
        $(this).text(text).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: It's work, thank you. I work like what I want after I put the dollar sign.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is like:

```
function() {
  // code 
}();
```

[IIFEs](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) don't work that way. Wrap the function into ()s:

```
(function() {
  // code 
})();
```

And it works.

There are [**other ways**](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/#iife) for you to "activate" the function as well. The best style is up to argument. All I recommend is pick one and use it consistently.

[See jsbin demo here.](http://jsbin.com/focamapiye/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: thank for the correction :)